# Can you play GTA 5, haven't played GTA 4?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

Would the story make sense? Would you miss on something?

Comment: I haven't played any of the GTA games, but I'm 100% confident in saying "Yes, you can play GTA5 without playing GTA4", because I don't think the games have any connecting story.

Comment: The only things I could think of are minor eastereggs and references to the previous games. Usually GTA games have completely individual stories.

Comment: Yes. GTA5 does not require GTA4 for installment. Also the story does not build upon GTA4

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The stories of GTAV and GTAIV are entirely separate. You can play either without the other and the story will make sense.

Comment: There are a few very minor references and nods to previous games, but you are not missing anything significant if you start with 5.